# vbs - 800A0401 - Expected End of Statement

Tags: vbscript

The bat has 
`>>%vbs% echo oShellLink.IconLocation = "%1, 0"`to produce

> oShellLink.IconLocation = ""C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.exe", 0"`

where %1 is a quoted path

However, unless I remove the quotes from path like here:

> oShellLink.IconLocation = "C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.exe, 0"

I get the titular error. What do you suggest? (Note that %1 is always supplied with quotes)

Also, I'm not very familiar with vbscript, why does it require no quotes next to each other?

...

Still not clear why vbscript can't interpret this assignment, but found a fix:
%~1 - Expands %1 and removes any surrounding quotation marks ("").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBS you need to escape double quote characters with a second double quote character.

So change

`>>%vbs% echo oShellLink.IconLocation = "%1, 0"`

to

`>>%vbs% echo oShellLink.IconLocation = ""%1", 0"`

Which in the VBS file will give you

`oShellLink.IconLocation = """C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.exe"", 0"`

Which parses out to `"C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.exe", 0` before being assigned to .IconLocation.

*Edit (additional info):*

Basically, the error is thrown if you put a non-escaped quote in the (not literal) string.

This is because the parser thinks it (the quote character) is the end marker of the string, which leaves garbage (the remaining characters) after it.

So, since the closing quote is supposed to be the 'end of the statement' marker, but it finds characters after that closing quote, there's an error because it "Expected" that was the "End of Statement".

The path works with and without the escaped quotes wrapping it because of the way .IconLocation intelligently parses the list of arguments you are feeding it as a single String.

Comment: My understanding of how this works (please correct it if needed): it sees assignment, so it strips outside double quotes in rhs. Then any double next to each other are converted to a literal double quote. But if they're not literal somehow they cause an error.

Comment: Your explanation of how they parse is correct.  I'll try to clarify why that error is coming up a little in an edit to my question (due to room).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem  is this line

```
oShellLink.IconLocation = ""C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.exe", 0"
```

You have a "" which is the quote escape character.  This basically lets you have a string that contains a quote without having a parser error. Like so:

```
" this is a string literal that contains a "" quote character"
```

stores

> this is a string literal that contains a " quote character

Comment: So how do I strip the quotes from %1 if they're not needed?